# Spring: Properly use of lombok Builder

Tags: spring, lombok

I faced with problem while using of lombok @Builder.

In SpringBoot application I create the following component:

```
@Getter
@Builder
@Component
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ContentDTO {
    private UUID uuid;
    private ContentAction contentAction;
    private String payload;
}
```

But when I run the application< I receive:

```
 Error creating bean with name 'contentDTO': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0
```

Caused by:

```
 No qualifying bean of type 'java.util.UUID' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate
```

"Finger to the sky", I changed lombok-builder to custom builder, like this:

```
 @Getter
 @Component
public class ContentDTO {

  private ContentDTO() {       
  }

 // fields

  public static Builder newBuilder() {
       return new ContentDTO().new Builder();
  }

 public class Builder{
    private Builder() {
        private constructor
    }


  public ContentDTO build() {
       return ContentDTO.this;
      }     
   }
}
```

And problem is gone.

Its nice, but I clearly dont understand, what was problem!

Why in this case lombok-builder prevented the autowiring of beans?

And how to use lombok-builder properly in Spring ApplicationContext?

Answer (score 1):

the use of the builder requires a default constructor. When you added the **@AllArgsConstructor** annotation the problem appears. therefore, you must also add the **@NoArgsConstructor** annotation. That should be the solution for your code.

Answer (score 1):

Well `ContentDTO` has the `@Component` annotation therefore *Spring* tried to pick up and register an instance of `ContentDTO` in order to do so It tried to create an instance using all args constructor generated by *Lombock* since it was the only available constructor.

It failed due to it couldn't find registered beans with the given types expected by the ContentDTO constructor.

Adding `@NoArgsConstructor` or a default constructor without args like you did will work, the Builder is not related.